# Is there an elegant way to recreate an object when I need to change its type?

Tags: java, class, object, abstract

A practice task of mine is about having Fighters taking part in Missions and an aggregator class that can count/filter/keep track of Fighters and Missions.

I have a Fighter abstract class and three different types of fighters (Junior, Medior and Senior) that inherit this abstract class with a number of fields.

The programme should be able to promote fighters to a higher rank - a Junior to Medior and a Medior to Senior. I understand it is not possible to change an object's type after it has been initialised, but is there a better / more elegant solution than my current one? i.e. I create a new object of a higher level fighter, copy the original object's data into it and then just delete the original object.

Comment: Why not to have  `rank` as class variable? Then you would not need sub-classing.

Comment: Based on your reply to the answer, I suggest you look into the [Decorator Pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=decorator+pattern+java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355098/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-recreate-an-object-when-i-need-to-change-its-type/77356296#comment136371687_77355098), it sounds like *rank* should simply be a property of your `Fighter` class.

You should not use inheritance unless the subclasses have additional data or behavior beyond that of the superclass.

Here is an entire example class. We define `Rank` as an enum with three named constant objects, your three levels of rank. We have a getter as well as a setter method for you to alter the rank field on an instance.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class Fighter
{
    // Member fields
    private String name;
    private Rank rank;

    enum Rank { JUNIOR, MEDIOR, SENIOR; }

    // Constructor
    public Fighter ( String name ,
                     Rank rank )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    // Accessors
    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( final String name )
    {
       this.name = name ;
    }

    public Rank getRank ( )
    {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank ( final Rank rank )
    {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    // `Object` overrides.
    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass ( ) != this.getClass ( ) ) return false;
        var that = ( Fighter ) obj;
        return Objects.equals ( this.name , that.name ) &&
                Objects.equals ( this.rank , that.rank );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash ( name , rank );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Fighter[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "rank=" + rank + ']';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Fighter alice = new Fighter ( "Alice" , Fighter.Rank.MEDIOR ) ;
alice.setRank( Rank.SENIOR ) ;  // Alice earned a promotion.
```

Comment: ...and they can be demoted.

Comment: Hi Basil,
Thanks, this is reasonable and I thought about it. I forgot to mention that the three types of Fighters can fight different missions, so for example Juniors can only do Mission A, Mediors A and B, and Seniors A, B, C. The MissionTypes are stored in enums. Currently these types are stored in static variables in each Fighter class. If I followed your example, I would have to store one list and set the MissionTypes in the constructor. This sounds and seems reasonable by me, however, I was warned against using too much logic in constructors. What's your take on this? Cheers, T

Comment: @tmsnvk Constructors should indeed be kept simple. However, data validation of inputs is a legitimate function for a constructor if it can be kept simple (if not simple, use a builder). When validating an assigned mission, use an [exhaustive `switch` statement](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441) with a case for each rank. If the mission is wrong for that rank, throw an illegal argument exception. Tip: You can use `EnumSet` to keep a set of missions appropriate for each rank; call `Set#contains`.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque for your detailed explanations, much appreciated!